# How to listen callback JS?

Tags: javascript

I have callback in interface:

```
interface {
  onLoad?: () => void;

}
```

I tried to catch this callback using this:

```
props.onLoad(() => this.mapLoaded = true);
```

But I get this error:

> Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: *"I tried to catch this callback"* What do you mean by *catch*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say for certain without more context, but you're probably meant to assign to `onLoad` rather than call it:

```
props.onLoad = () => this.mapLoaded = true;
```

Typically, a callback is called by the object you're passing the interface to, so that it can *call back* to your code when something happens (in this case, presumably when a map is loaded).